# Pass string if the parameter value is null

Tags: c#

I need to pass multiple parameters in a function. My requirement is the parameter value should not be NULL. If
the parameter is NULL pass "TBD" instead.

e.g.

```
getBookInfo (string bookId, string bookName, string bookAuthor) 
//if any of the parameters is NULL, pass "TBD" string in parameter
```

How can I do this? Can I do this using ternary operator, and if so, how?

Comment: `parameter??"TBD"`

Comment: You can assign default values to parameters if you can change the definition, 
BookInfo getBookInfo (string bookId="TBD", string bookName="TBD", string bookAuthor="TBD")

Comment: If the "TBD" requirement applies every time the function is called, I wouldn't put it in the call: I'd put it in the body of the function. Like HarveySpecter's answer. If for some reason it only applies to this one particular call and in other cases nulls are fine -- which seems unlikely to me but I don't know your requirements -- then Enigmativity's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try doing it this way when calling your method:

```
getBookInfo (bookId ?? "TBD", bookName ?? "TBD", bookAuthor ?? "TBD");
```

The ternary operator `?:` is a waste when you can use the null coalescing operator `??`.

Comment: how to pass "TBD" for NULL, when the parameter is class property i.e. suppose ClassName.classProperty is passed as parameter. Please explain.

Comment: @user4221591 - If you have a new question you should post it as such. However, if you're just asking if you can do `ClassName.classProperty ?? "TBD"` then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2):

Just put an `if` condition inside this function and check for `null` values of these three variables and if found `null`, you can assign the default values immediately after the `if` check and then continue further execution.

Something like this :

```
getBookInfo (string bookId, string bookName, string bookAuthor)
{
   bookId = (bookId == "" ) ? bookId : "TBD";
   // other variables same way.
}
```

Hope this clears it.

Answer (score 1):

Using ternary it would be like:

```
getBookInfo (bookId == null ? "TBD" : bookId, bookName == null ? "TBD" : bookName, bookAuthor == null ? "TBD" : bookAuthor)
```

but I think that is not very clear to read...

Answer (score 1):

```
private void GetBookInfo(string bookId, string bookName, string bookAuthor)
        {
            // if any of the parameter is NULL, set "TBD" as the value
            bookId = bookId == null ? "TBD" : bookId;
            bookName = bookName == null ? "TBD" : bookName;
            bookAuthor = bookAuthor == null ? "TBD" : bookAuthor;

            // rest of the code goes here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before passing parameter check whether parameter is null or not. For example

```
string bookid;
string bookName;
string bookAuthor;
if(bookid==null)
bookid="TBD";
if(bookName==null)
bookName="TBD";
if(bookAuthor==null)
bookAuthor="TBD";
getBookInfo (string bookId, string bookName, string bookAuthor)
```

This will set value "TBD" if value of any field would be null. Hope it resolved your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could also provide an overload of the method which would allow the developer to provide a limited number of parameters. The overload would call the method with additional parameters passing default values for parameters it doesn't already have.

```
public void GetBookInfo (string bookID)
{
    // Call overload passing bookID and empty string as book name
    return GetBookInfo(bookId, string.Empty);
}

public void GetBookInfo (string bookID, string bookName)
{
    // Call overload passing bookID, bookName and empty string as author
    return GetBookInfo(bookId, bookName, string.Empty);
}

public void GetBookInfo (string bookID, string bookName, string author)
{
    // All 3 parameters are populated here, get the book info...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the newer versions of C# you can do this (add default values to arguments):

```
public void getBookInfo (string bookId = "TBD", string bookName = "TBD", string bookAuthor = "TBD")
```

This also makes the arguments optional.